# How do I add a Liferay non-group page?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'd like to create a notification page that is not tied to a user or group, similar to how Liferay handles PayPal integration. Maybe I simply haven't found the correct URL.

If you're not familiar with how Liferay handles PayPal integration, here's a summary (assumes you've configured the shopping portlet to use PayPal, of course).

- When the user checks out with PayPal, the page is redirected to
  PayPal for login and payment processing.
- When Liferay redirects to PayPal, it passes a notification URL to
  PayPal per PayPal specifications.
- Once the user has approved payment, Paypal contacts Liferay using
  this URL (something like `http://myserver/c/shopping/notify`).
- PayPal passes parameters with the URL to verify amount and payment,
  so the shopping portlet can mark the purchase as completed.

I've tried to add a page (/myservice/confirm) alongside the other pages in my portlet using JSF, and tried to invoke it along the lines of `http://myserver/c/myportal/confirm`, with no luck.

Is there something else I need to be doing?

Thanks.

Comment: /shopping/notify represent struts action url, what is /myservice/confirm in your case? Can you give more info for your requirement?

Comment: The /myportal/confirm is a JSF page with an associated bean. The bean would process the parameters from PayPal, similar to the PayPalNotificationAction class in Liferay. Right now confirm.xhtml is just a placeholder copied from a simple page.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you require a custom URL which should not be tied to any user-pages nor group-pages, something like `/c/blogs/findEntry?entryId=?` which liferay uses to direct to the page which has the blogs portlet.

So if that is the case you can create one using a **Struts-action hook**. In the liferay-hook.xml you can create a URL as

```
<struts-action-path>/portal/mycustom/customURL</struts-action-path>
```

So now if you hit the URL `http://myserver/c/portal/mycustom/customURL`, you will be directed to your custom action. In the custom action you can process and direct to the page of the portal which is attached to a Site or User.

Here is the link to the official documentation for using struts-action hook: [Adding and Overriding Struts Action](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/lp-6-1-dgen06-overriding-and-adding-struts-actions-0).

---

If this is not what you want and instead you want to add a physical page in which you can add portlets as well. Then it is not possible to have a page without being attached to User, UserGroup or Site (Group).

Also if you want to directly show your JSP with a URL, that is not possible. Since portlets are the ones that show JSP or JSF. Still you can do the following to give a feel that this is a separate page:

1. So you can have a hidden page created, may be in guest site with URL `/myNotify`.
2. Have your portlet in that page with full-page layout.
3. Create a struts action or [filter-hook](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/other-hooks-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-10-en) to intercept your custom-URL.
4. Process request and re-direct to the page `/myNotify` with the portlet and your portlet will show the notification message.

Hope this helps.